# Shopify Custom Product Rendering (Display 3 or 4 products based on button click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, customizing

I have page which displays list of products on my website. On clicking the (3 columns icon, it should display 3 products per row, on clicking 4 column it should display 4 products per row).

we are using turbo theme (latest).

From admin section ( ShopifyAdmin->Customize->Collection-> products_per_row (changing it to 3/4 it is working as expected). I wanted to do the same requirement on application.) 
Any help appreciated.

- Options that i have explored (changing the turbo theme framework classes, it is not working as expected)

Thanks,
Rakesh [t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gWJ2.png)

Comment: I have see this "question" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586481/shopify-click-on-different-button-will-run-different-liquid-code
This is my exact requirement which matches my problem. But the solution was not clear to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is not a "write me my code" platform. You have to provide a code that you have tried to implement yourself and we can help you with a solution. In your case you will have to hire a developer to help you with this if you have no knowledge in development.

Comment: Thanks drip, i was looking for pointers for rendering liquid code based on button click.  Change turbo theme classes ,if suggested any  by (Shopify exposure people)